# The preference of using Present Perfect Continuos

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-constructions, perfect-aspect

This is a translating task. The key says that the answer is "did you speak" (off topic: "speak" or "talk"). But I'm pretty sure that I should use Present Perfect Continuous. In this case it is an exlusive form and we feel some kind of incompleteness, for example, "she is frustrated by his speech". Moreover speaker this question expresses some kind of author's anger, irritation or even criticism.

> Why have you been talking to her in that manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why have you talked to her in that manner?

This refers to manner regarding *one time* (one conversation) that you spoke to her.

> Why have you been talking to her in that manner?

This means you've been talking to her in that manner for a while.

Unless there is a single event of talking to her (e.g. one conversation), you are correct and should use the continuous tense.

Comment: thaks for explanation